# Overriding font-colors using CSS

Tags: css

I have a table with some elements in it. One of these elements have a different color than the one set to the container.

When I hover the container, I need the element with a different color to change to the new hover:color (white). I've tried using `!important`, but I can't quite get it working.

The element I am talking about is the one containing the text `2 hours ago`

Here's the current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/SKP6v/

Comment: seems to work.. what is the problem?

Comment: Why the downvote? It doesn't work as-is. The `2 hours ago` remains gray when hovering.

Comment: not on my computer it goes a kind of a wine color

Comment: The problem is not the background, it's the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
.mail_item:hover .mail_item_table_time {
    color: white;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SKP6v/1/